# Axios follow redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I currently have some JavaScript code in my front-end `React` application that makes `get/post requests` to my `Express` back-end with `axios`. 
My current back-end implementation can sometimes `redirect` to a different page if the input is invalid (to the login page in the following example)

```
//back-end logic
if(valid data) response.json(someData);
if(invalid data) response.redirect("/login");
```

My axios request is the following:

```
axios.get("some.url/api").then(res => {
    //work with the res.someData if valid
}
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The issue I am facing is that if `axios` receives the redirect response it fetches that page but I want to redirect the window to the redirected URL.

Is it possible to make axios redirect the user window to the redirected page with axios when it receives `response.redirect('url')` from `Express`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't.

The underlying API used by Axios in browsers follows redirects transparently.

---

Consider checking the content-type in the response and setting `location` to a new value if it is HTML rather than JSON.